# Calling all Batch Files in a Folder

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch file that will execute all of the batch files located in a folder.  So I have a folder that contains 6 (will increase) batch files, and I want to use a for loop to iterate through the list.  An easier way of understanding it would be like so:

```
for batchFile in folder:
  CALL batchFile
  cd Desktop
```

Each batch file should start after the other finishes.  Also, batch files will be the only type of files in the folder, so there shouldn't need to be any kind of separation.  It may sound odd, but both the call and the directory change need to be inside of the loop (due to directory changes in each of the batch files).
This is the closest thing I've found for getting a start on this:

```
 for /r %%i in "DIR" do CALL
```

Where "DIR" is the folder directory.  However, it 1) doesn't work and 2) would only do a CALL and not also a directory change.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Also, I'm using Windows 7.

Thanks.

EXTENSION:

Doing this in a bat file will work:

```
CALL "WelcomeScreenLists.bat"
cd directory
CALL "WelcomeScreenLinks.bat"
cd directory
CALL "RightClick.bat"
cd directory
CALL "RibbonButtons.bat"
cd directory
pause
```

"directory" is the full path of the folder containing the bat files.  I would like to turn this into a for loop that loops through all files in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you'd want something like this:

```
  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b ".\*.bat"') do (
    CALL %%i
  )
```

This works from the current directory.  You can hard-code a directory by replacing the first "." in the dir statement with the full directory name, like so:

```
  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b "c:\folder\subfolder\*.bat"') do (
    CALL %%i
  )
```

The "for /f" syntax will iterate over file names, the "dir" command is any valid dir command... you can use any options to control sort order, for example.

Comment: it didn't work :/ I put a pause after it to see what was going on.  The first few lines say that "Volume" is not recognized as an internal or external command.  I honestly have no idea where the word volume is coming from... Errors following that are using the inputs:  CALL 05/28/2014  02:02 PM.. which is when the files were last modified

Comment: Just a minor missing piece... need a /b in the dir command, like this:

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b ".\*.bat"') do (

Comment: it will run the first one correctly, but for each of the others, it says: 'file2.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file (same with file 3, file 4, etc.)

Comment: Also, I'm using the full directory name, without the .bat (the call function for some reason doesn't work with the extension).  When I tried the dir /b ".\*" it was opening way more files than it should

Comment: The batch files can't change the current working directory... that might be your problem.  Perhaps a "PUSHDIR" and "POPDIR" bracketing the CALL, or within the batch files themselves if you can rewrite those.  And your batch files should probably be *.cmd files (just change the extensions... I use exclusively *.cmd everywhere). You're just going to have to experiment around a little, because this DOES work... something else in your environment is mucking things up.

Comment: CALL "WelcomeScreenLists.bat"
cd directory
CALL "WelcomeScreenLinks.bat"
cd directory
CALL "RightClick.bat"
cd directory
CALL "RibbonButtons.bat"
cd directory
pause

it works (that's what's written in another bat file)

Comment: for readability purposes, I added the batch file as an extension above

Comment: Just add the "cd directory" above the CALL %%i statement then.  You can put an ECHO in front of it to just have it display what it WOULD execute so you can debug.  Again, this should be working for you.

Comment: putting the cd in the loop made it work (funny, I just tried that before reading your comment lol) thanks for the help